# How should I redo plumbing to fit new garbage disposal?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal, p-trap

Planning to replace InSinkErator [Badger 1](https://insinkerator.emerson.com/documents/badger-1-installation-care-use-manual-english-en-us-7832466.pdf) garbage disposal with [Evolution Compact](https://insinkerator.emerson.com/documents/evolution-compact-installation-care-use-manual-en-us-6867438.pdf) and it appears they have slightly different dimensions (5" vs 5-3/4"):

[image: Badger 1 dimensions]
[image: Evolution Compact]

How do you recommend changing this setup to fit the new garbage disposal with minimum required plumbing rework? Might I be able to replace the broken slip nut then loosen the other connections and wiggle everything to fit (disposal included - not sure how much choice you get with it's orientation?)? My concerns:

- P-trap looks different than others I'm seeing online. [Nut appears to receive threads from makeshift J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ3Mr.jpg) (others I'm seeing appear to receive threads from P-trap) and it appears to have extra connection points?
- All of the connections appear to have some sort of residue, perhaps from pipe dope? I assume loosening and reconnecting will require cleaning that off and applying new?

Not my work so far (and I assume it's from the original build) so lay it on with what must be changed and what should be changed.

(Ignore the bowls and paper towels, was doing some faucet work and making sure I have no leaks)

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]
[image: Pic 5]

Answer (score 1):

> Might I be able to replace the broken slip nut then loosen the other connections and wiggle everything to fit (disposal included - not sure how much choice you get with it's orientation?)?

Yes, that's exactly it. The disposal can be rotated to any angle. For a novice it is likely a two-person job: one person holds the disposal in position while the other person manipulates the clamp ring which holds the disposal to the bottom of the sink bowl. It might be possible instead to temporarily support the disposal from below with a stack of bowls, inverted bucket, blocks, storage containers, etc.

You'll probably need to shorten things slightly at the horizontal branch of the sanitary tee (arrow pointing leftward) and rotate the bottom half of the P trap and the sanitary tee itself a bit. It may also be necessary to slightly rotate the elbow below the strainer basket of the other sink bowl too. If the horizontal branch is too long it can be trimmed with just about any kind of saw, or even a good utility knife. Remove the burrs if any after trimming. The entire assembly may also need to move higher or lower depending on the elevation of the discharge port on the new disposal.

[image: sanitary tee movement]

Comment: Thanks. What do I need to do about the existing residue on the connection points? Should I be sealing the connection points with anything specifically? Looks like pipe dope is preferred over Teflon tape?

Comment: Are black slip joint nuts not sold individually? Not seeing any on HD or Lowe's online.

Comment: @bbodenmiller These joints are compression sealed; neither pipe dope nor teflon tape is used on the threads. The elbow at the P-trap exit will probably have a cone-shaped sealing face; all the other connections will probably (should?) have a soft wedge/cone-shaped sealing washer under the nut. Remove the residue so that the sealing surfaces are clean -- or buy new. Unfortunately HD and Lowes seem to have moved toward carrying drain kits rather than individual parts; they may not offer the nut individually.

Comment: Building plumbing often uses white PVC or black ABS. Because those are joined by solvent welding one must normally stick with just one color (ie type of plastic). Under-sink drain plumbing is different. It's often polypropylene plastic regardless of whether you choose the white parts or the black parts. Here you can use either color, even mix and match, depending on aesthetics and/or availability.

Comment: If I were to replace the P-trap what am I looking for to attach to existing makeshift J? It looks non-traditional since the threads appear to be on the J.

Comment: Went to the store today, looks like I'm looking for captured or captive nut? Like [this J-bend](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Sink-Trap-J-bend/1071565) or [this P-trap](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-IN-ABS-P-TRAP-W-UNION/1003028100).

Comment: @bbodenmiller Your trap is ABS like the one you linked but has a [separate trap adapter](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-IN-TRAP-ADAPTER-PLUG/1003028206) glued to it. Buy one of those and test whether its nut fits the adapter that's on your P-trap. It probably will fit, but if not: your trap has a Mueller logo visible, so the trap adapter might be Mueller as well. They're still in the business; if you bought a Mueller brand adapter the nut included with it would almost certainly fit yours. Or start removing & replacing the ABS parts.

Comment: I assume the trap adapter is glued to the U? Any particular reason I can't just replace U & trap adapter with the [P-trap](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-IN-ABS-P-TRAP-W-UNION/1003028100) (or maybe [this one](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-IN-P-TRAP-NUT/1003028114)) & connect T to that?

Comment: @bbodenmiller If the parts fit use 'em! The trap in your photo has a Mueller logo visible. The Charlotte brand might fit well enough, but if it doesn't, you could track down Mueller parts with good reason to hope they'd mix-and-match well.

Comment: The [P-trap](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-IN-ABS-P-TRAP-W-UNION/1003028100) worked! Just a bit of a pain getting the old one off since they glued it together.